# MySQL Bin-Log Courupped

Tags: mysql, replication

In the recent time we have found that the bin log is getting corrupted, 20% binlog files were having errors, which couldn't even pass the sanity check by `mysqlbinlog -u user -p mysql-bin.000021 | head -5`.

Consider me new to MySQL, Is there a way which can reduce binlog corruption or some parameter which is safe for binlog/replication. What is the best way for replication, `Master-Master` or `Master-Slave`? Is there a way to get auto backup weekly or monthly.

Edited as per request

```
[root@host mysql]# mysqlbinlog --verbose --base64-output=decode-rows mysql-bin.000089 | tail -n 5 | head -n 1  
ERROR: Error in Log_event::read_log_event(): 'Sanity check failed', data_len: 541414465, event_type: 116  
ERROR: Could not read entry at offset 184469: Error in log format or read error.  
DELIMITER ;  

[root@host mysql]# mysqlbinlog --verbose --base64-output=decode-rows mysql-bin.000086 | tail -n 5 | head -n 1
ERROR: Error in Log_event::read_log_event(): 'Event too big', data_len: -736930139, event_type: 71
ERROR: Could not read entry at offset 668651590: Error in log format or read error.
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Auto backup -- nothing "off the shelf".  Master-Master is problematical unless you write to only one at a time.

Comment: What "corruption" do you see?

Comment: There was a power failure, and the Binlog got corrupted editing the question please have a look.